# Typescript styled-component error: "Type '{ children: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Getting a typescript error on my styled-component

> Type '{ children: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2559)

```
import React from 'react'

import { NotificationSuccess, NotificationError } from '../../styles'

interface IProps {
  error?: boolean;
  message: string;
}

export const Notification = (props: IProps) => {
  const Note = () => props.error ? NotificationError : NotificationSuccess;
  // Error happens on <Note>
  return (<Note>{props.message}</Note>);
}
```

And the styles:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const NotificationDiv = styled.div`
  z-index: 11;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -160px;
  top: 1rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  width: 320px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: ${props => props.theme.offWhite};
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
`

export const NotificationSuccess = styled(NotificationDiv)`
  background: ${props => props.theme.green};
`

export const NotificationError = styled(NotificationDiv)`
  background: ${props => props.theme.red};
`
```

[image]

I found this answer here, and I did upgrade my package.json to the following, but that still didn't help:

[Why this wrapped styled-component errors "has no properties in common with"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53724583/why-this-wrapped-styled-component-errors-has-no-properties-in-common-with/53902817#53902817)

```
"styled-components": "4.0.3",
"@types/styled-components": "4.0.3",
"babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
```

Full package.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next -p 7777",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 8000",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --watch --no-cache",
    "test-win": "SET NODE_ENV=test&& jest --watch"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-typescript": "^1.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "decko": "^1.2.0",
    "downshift": "^2.2.3",
    "enzyme": "^3.6.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.5.0",
    "graphql": "^14.0.2",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.9.2",
    "graphql-tools": "^4.0.0",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "next": "^7.0.2",
    "next-routes": "^1.4.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "ramda": "^0.26.1",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-adopt": "^0.6.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.5.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "4.0.3",
    "tslint": "^5.12.1",
    "tslint-react": "^3.6.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4",
    "waait": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.3.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.1.15",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.13",
    "@types/next": "^7.0.6",
    "@types/ramda": "^0.25.49",
    "@types/react": "^16.7.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.11",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.0.1",
    "@types/styled-components": "4.0.3",
    "@types/zeit__next-typescript": "^0.1.1",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-sass-vars": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
    "casual": "^1.5.19",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.4",
    "jest": "^24.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js",
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/.next/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ],
    "transform": {
      ".*": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.ts?$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts",
      "tsx"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>/components/",
      "<rootDir>/pages/",
      "<rootDir>/shared/"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try deleting `node_modules` and reinstalling?

Comment: Please consider defining the function component as a generic type based on the interface. e.g. const Notification: React.FC<IProps>

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`<Note>{props.message}</Note>` is same as `Note({ children: props.message })` so TypeScript is complaining that function `Note` doesn't take any arguments and function type doesn't match. It has nothing to do with styled-components.

([`IntrinsicAttributes`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/4cce72c390b746dd85543b4a8379cf4977582893/types/react/index.d.ts#L2783) is probably the default interface you extend when you write a functional component. Or something like that idk xD)

My best guess is you want `const Note = props.error ? NotificationError : NotificationSuccess;` instead of what you have written.

PS. I might be wrong but I'm mostly sure this is the case.

Comment: You were right, yeah I didn't need the `= () =>` part.

Answer (score 60):

If you create a  component:

```html
<DeliverNow>

</DeliverNow>
```

it automatically receives `props`. When you declare it:

```js
const DeliverNow = () => {}
```

TypeScript will tell you that they don't match, since in reality, `DeliverNow` receives `props`.

It should actually be:

```js
const DeliverNow = (props:any) => {}
```

Comment: No, it should not be `any` as it's discouraged to use. I have solved it by removing React.FC and adding children prop with the type `React.ReactNode`.

Answer (score 7):

In react 18 they removed `children` as a default prop on the FC type. One potential fix is to do

```
export const Asdf = ({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) => {
// instead of 
export const Asdf: React.FC = ({children}) => {
```

Answer (score 4):

I got this error:

> Type '{ children: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts

When dynamically added tags in my react application.
I found a great solution that has nothing to do with typescript or styled-components.

It is enough to create a node through `React.createElement`

For example:

```
const Title: React.SFC<TitleProps> = ({ tag, styled, children }) =>
  React.createElement(tag, { ...styled }, children);

const TitleStyled = styled(Title)`Your styled`
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of using function declaration, use function expression.
EX:

```js
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was the fix for me. I was trying to name my own component the same name as a dependency component and VS Code automatically imported from the dependency instead of my component.

Answer (score 1):

As you can read on the Component documentation:

```js
/**
 * A general `Component` has no implicit `children` prop.  If desired, you can
 * specify one as in `Component<{name: String, children: JSX.Element>}`.
 */
export declare type Component<P = {}> = (props: P) => JSX.Element;
```

So, in order to get rid of this warn, you must pass a generic that includes the children or whatever props you want. The correct implementation is:

```js
export const Notification: Component<IProps> = (props) => {
  const Note = () => props.error ? NotificationError : NotificationSuccess;
  // Error happens on <Note>
  return (<Note>{props.message}</Note>);
}
```

You wont need to declare the props type, since it is intrinsic to the `Component<P>`.

Answer (score 0):

Most common case to get that error is when you name your styled-component the same name as function component. Just give some postfix to your style components like `ButtonStyled` or `ButtonContainer` and you are g2g