# Type '{ children: never[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes' when using material-ui with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to typescript and trying to use an existing component  i.e tabs from material-ui.

SimpleTab.ts:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

interface TabPanelProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  index: any;
  value: any;
}

function TabPanel(props: TabPanelProps) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box p={3}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

function a11yProps(index: any) {
  return {
    id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
    'aria-controls': `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
}));

export default function SimpleTabs() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, newValue: number) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="simple tabs example">
          <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>


      </AppBar>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
     tab 1
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
     tab 2
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
     tab 3
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and I've used inside homepage as below:

HomePage.ts:

```
import react , { useRef } from "react";
import SimpleTabs from '../Tabs/Tabs'

export default function Homepage(){
    const HomeheaderTabs = useRef<typeof SimpleTabs | null>(null);
    return(
        {HomeheaderTabs}

   )}
```

And this I'm using this homepage in the main page as below:

```
import React from 'react';
import Homepage from '../src/Components/HomePage/Homepage'

export default function App() {
  return (<>
    <Homepage>
      </>;);

}
```

I'm getting error in the return that this type has no children error.

I saw the below link, but I'm using material UI.

[Typescript styled-component error: "Type '{ children: string; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129942/typescript-styled-component-error-type-children-string-has-no-properti)

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: What you're returning in `HomePage.ts` seems very incorrect. That's not JSX.

Comment: Could you please suggest how to return it...as it was throwing error if I return the component directly

Comment: I got the solution.Its because instead of <Homepage />  I was using <Homepage>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are closing your components properly so in this case the `'/'` was missing from `<Homepage />` as suggested by Hema