# What is the type of a component passed in a HOC?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am converting a protectedRoute HOC with AWS-Amplify from Javascript to TypeScript.

This HOC will be used to protect any routes that require authentication. If the user is not signed in it will redirect them to a specific route.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";


interface Props {
  history: string[];
}

const protectedRoute = (Comp: React.FunctionComponent, route = "/profile") => (
  props: Props
) => {
  async function checkAuthState() {
    try {
      await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    } catch (error) {
      props.history.push(route);
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuthState();
  }, []);
  return <Comp {...props} />;
};

export default protectedRoute;
```

Example of using the HOC for a protected route

```
const Protected = () => {
  return <Container>Protected</Container>;
};

export default protectedRoute(Protected);
```

The error I am getting from `<Comp {...props} />`:

```
Type '{ history: string[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

I cannot figure out what type to use for `Comp` but I am passing in a functional component and `const Protected` returns a `JSX.Element`.

I tried setting `Comp` to be `React.ReactNode` but get the same result.

I am also aware that the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129942/typescript-styled-component-error-type-children-string-has-no-properti) mentions that I should just use `any` but I want to know if there is a proper type to use here.

Comment: what line of your code does the error point to? with route you mean react-router route?

Comment: I edited the question to show the exact line and yes I am using react-router-dom for routing.

Comment: `React.FunctionComponent<Props>` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `React.FunctionComponent<Props>` to explicitly tell the type to use your `Props` interface.

Note that the `children` prop is implicitly included with `React.FunctionComponent` but that will change in a future version of `@types/react`. You can read more information [here](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react/blob/main/README.md#function-components).